# nodejs + WS Read Timeout

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs ws websocket library.
How can set socket read timeout on ws library?

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, 
    wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setTimeout as example below:

```
ws.on('message', function message(data, flags) {
  console.log('Roundtrip time: ' + (Date.now() - parseInt(data)) + 'ms', flags);

  setTimeout(function timeout() {
    ws.send(Date.now().toString(), {mask: true});
  }, 500);
});
```